# Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, mocking, karma-runner

I want to use the mock to make a new class,but i don't konw why this mock does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'.following is my code.

```js
import {} from 'jasmine';
import * as angular from 'angular';
import {StrategyTables} from "./strategyTables.component";
import {StrategyTablesService} from "./strategyTables.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Location } from '@angular/common';
import {inject,async,TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
describe('strategyTables.component',() => {

  class MockstrategyService extends StrategyTablesService{
    getContactById(id:number){
      return{
        "name": "lee"
      };
    }

  }
  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module(($provide) => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          $provide.value(StrategyTablesService, { useClass:MockstrategyService })
      ]
    });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to install the typings for angular mock (`@types/angular-mocks`) which is in another project than the angularjs one (`@types/angular`).

```
npm install --save-dev @types/angular-mocks
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the following would probably be preferred:
`import 'angular-mocks';` which can be added at the top of your file.

Comment: top of my file is `import * as angular from 'angular'; import 'angular-mocks';` but it is still not working.

Comment: Don't forget the jasmine import

Comment: import 'angular-mocks' leads to `Can't resolve 'angular-mocks'` for me...any idea why?

Comment: I added import angular-mocks and still have the same issue